# pre-commit only seems to indicate the files to modify

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

if I use pre-commit I can see the files that should be modified, but they are not modified.

More exactly:

```
$ pre-commit install
pre-commit installed at .git/hooks/pre-commit
$ pre-commit run --all-files
check for added large files..............................................Passed
check python ast.........................................................Passed
check for case conflicts.................................................Passed
check docstring is first.................................................Passed
check json...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
check for merge conflicts................................................Passed
check toml...............................................................Passed
check xml................................................................Passed
check yaml...............................................................Passed
debug statements (python)................................................Passed
fix end of files.........................................................Passed
fix python encoding pragma...............................................Passed
python tests naming..................................(no files to check)Skipped
trim trailing whitespace.................................................Passed
black....................................................................Failed
- hook id: black
- files were modified by this hook

reformatted python/populse_mia/data_manager/database_mia.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/modify_table.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist/mia_anatomist.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/data_manager/data_loader.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/count_table.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/data_manager/data_history_inspect.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/advanced_search.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist_2/mia_anatomist.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/iteration_table.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/mini_viewer.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/software_properties.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/type_editors.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/main.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/process_mia.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/data_manager/project.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/utils/utils.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist_2/anasimpleviewer2.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/node_controller.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/main_window.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/process_library.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_manager_tab.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py
reformatted python/populse_mia/test.py

All done! ✨  ✨
25 files reformatted, 24 files left unchanged.

interrogate..............................................................Passed
isort (python)...........................................................Failed
- hook id: isort
- files were modified by this hook

Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/data_manager/data_history_inspect.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/software_properties.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/mini_viewer.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/process_library.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/modify_table.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/iteration_table.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/advanced_search.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/type_editors.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/data_manager/data_loader.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/process_mia.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/utils/utils.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist_2/anasimpleviewer2.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/data_manager/project.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/test.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist/mia_anatomist.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/data_manager/database_mia.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_manager_tab.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/count_table.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/main.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/node_controller.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist_2/mia_anatomist.py
Fixing /data/Git_Projects/populse_mia/python/populse_mia/user_interface/main_window.py

flake8 under python3.....................................................Failed
- hook id: flake8
- exit code: 1

python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/iteration_table.py:284:80: E501 line too long (102 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/iteration_table.py:291:80: E501 line too long (106 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/iteration_table.py:300:80: E501 line too long (98 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/iteration_table.py:303:80: E501 line too long (105 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/iteration_table.py:310:80: E501 line too long (105 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/iteration_table.py:361:80: E501 line too long (109 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/process_mia.py:575:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:26:1: F401 'json' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:74:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:75:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:86:80: E501 line too long (92 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:127:80: E501 line too long (120 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:133:80: E501 line too long (97 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:144:80: E501 line too long (86 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:157:80: E501 line too long (97 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:169:80: E501 line too long (98 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:174:80: E501 line too long (98 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/data_manager/project.py:22:1: F401 'datetime.timedelta' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/data_manager/project.py:729:9: F841 local variable 'procs' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/data_manager/project.py:813:9: F401 'soma_workflow.client as swclient' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/data_manager/project.py:814:9: F401 'soma_workflow.constants' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/data_manager/project.py:1245:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/data_manager/project.py:1385:24: E711 comparison to None should be 'if cond is not None:'
python/populse_mia/data_manager/project.py:1569:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:24:1: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/test.py:159:1: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/test.py:259:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:497:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:583:80: E501 line too l    python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:28:1: F401 're' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:34:1: F401 'capsul.api.capsul_engine' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:42:1: F401 'PyQt5.QtGui' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:43:1: F401 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/test.py:4510:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:4511:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:4511:80: E501 line too long (144 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4512:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:4513:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:4513:80: E501 line too long (113 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4514:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '    python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:28:1: F401 're' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:34:1: F401 'capsul.api.capsul_engine' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:42:1: F401 'PyQt5.QtGui' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:43:1: F401 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:169:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:259:33: E713 test for membership should be 'not in'
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:318:80: E501 line too long (85 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_editor.py:545:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist_2/anasimpleviewer2.py:39:1: F401 'optparse.OptionParser' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist_2/anasimpleviewer2.py:50:1: E402 module level import not at top of file
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist_2/__init__.py:3:1: F401 '.mia_anatomist.MiaViewer' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/data_manager/project_properties.py:24:1: F401 'populse_mia.software_properties.verCmp' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/data_manager/project_properties.py:116:9: F841 local variable 'exc' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:33:80: E501 line too long (115 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:44:80: E501 line too long (96 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:46:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:58:80: E501 line too long (112 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:59:80: E501 line too long (112 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/#install_mia.py:72:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4515:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:4515:80: E501 line too long (118 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4516:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:4517:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:4517:80: E501 line too long (115 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4518:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:4519:9: E265 block comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:4524:80: E501 line too long (92 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4653:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4658:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4666:80: E501 line too long (92 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4668:80: E501 line too long (93 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4669:80: E501 line too long (88 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4670:80: E501 line too long (93 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4671:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4673:80: E501 line too long (94 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4676:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:4890:36: E262 inline comment should start with '# '
python/populse_mia/test.py:5218:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:5384:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:5397:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:5422:80: E501 line too long (86 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:5425:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:5515:49: E231 missing whitespace after ','
python/populse_mia/test.py:5520:49: E231 missing whitespace after ','
python/populse_mia/test.py:5528:49: E231 missing whitespace after ','
python/populse_mia/test.py:5580:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:5649:9: E731 do not assign a lambda expression, use a def
python/populse_mia/test.py:5943:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:6017:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:6024:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:6118:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:6140:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:6180:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/test.py:6217:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/test.py:6338:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:6674:9: F841 local variable 'index_DOCUMENT_2' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/test.py:6695:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:7456:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:7519:80: E501 line too long (87 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:7522:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:8091:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:8098:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/test.py:8816:80: E501 line too long (102 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2032:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2049:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2063:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2077:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2091:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2094:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2104:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2115:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2138:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2143:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2153:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2167:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2172:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:2181:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:3451:59: E713 test for membership should be 'not in'
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:3522:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:3536:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:3575:25: F841 local variable 'e' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:3676:21: F523 '...'.format(...) has unused arguments at position(s): 0
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:3961:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:3977:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:4021:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:4158:16: E713 test for membership should be 'not in'
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:4200:16: E713 test for membership should be 'not in'
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:4681:9: F841 local variable 'h_box' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:5333:17: F841 local variable 'e' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:5348:80: E501 line too long (95 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:5385:21: E722 do not use bare 'except'
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:5387:80: E501 line too long (95 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pop_ups.py:5883:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist/mia_anatomist.py:4:80: E501 line too long (106 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist/mia_anatomist.py:23:80: E501 line too long (92 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist/mia_anatomist.py:24:80: E501 line too long (96 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist/mia_anatomist.py:38:9: E731 do not assign a lambda expression, use a def
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_viewer/anatomist/__init__.py:3:1: F401 '.mia_anatomist.MiaViewer' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/data_manager/database_mia.py:22:1: F401 
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_manager_tab.py:3311:9: F841 local variable 'timer' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_manager_tab.py:3367:9: F841 local variable 'capsul_config' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/user_interface/pipeline_manager/pipeline_manager_tab.py:3486:13: F401 'soma_workflow.gui.workflowGui.SomaWorkflowWidget' imported but unused
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py:743:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py:756:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py:769:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py:1047:25: E713 test for membership should be 'not in'
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py:1755:9: E266 too many leading '#' for block comment
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py:2633:9: F841 local variable 'collection_init' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py:2634:9: F841 local variable 'primary_key_init' is assigned to but never used
python/populse_mia/user_interface/data_browser/data_browser.py:2808:16: E713 test for membership should be 'not in'
python/populse_mia/main.py:350:1: E402 module level import not at top of file
python/populse_mia/main.py:352:1: E402 module level import not at top of file
python/populse_mia/main.py:354:1: E402 module level import not at top of file
python/populse_mia/main.py:356:1: E402 module level import not at top of file
python/populse_mia/main.py:357:1: E402 module level import not at top of file
python/populse_mia/user_interface/main_window.py:1436:80: E501 line too long (80 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/main_window.py:1702:80: E501 line too long (90 > 79 characters)
python/populse_mia/user_interface/main_window.py:1705:80: E501 line too long (94 > 79 characters)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   properties/config.yml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Maybe I did the configuration wrong?

This is the .pre-commit-config.yaml:

```
$ more .pre-commit-config.yaml
repos:

-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks: # general hooks
    -   id: check-added-large-files
    -   id: check-ast
    -   id: check-case-conflict
    -   id: check-docstring-first
    -   id: check-json
    -   id: check-merge-conflict
    -   id: check-toml
    -   id: check-xml
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: debug-statements
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: fix-encoding-pragma
    -   id: name-tests-test
    -   id: trailing-whitespace

-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 23.1.0
    hooks: # code formatter
    -   id: black
        language: python
        args: ["--line-length=79"]

-   repo: https://github.com/econchick/interrogate
    rev: 1.5.0
    hooks: # documentation checker
    -   id: interrogate
        args: [--fail-under=80, -vv]

-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.12.0
    hooks: # imports sorting
    -   id: isort
        name: isort (python)

-   repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
    rev: 3.9.2
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
        name: flake8 under python3
        language_version: python3
```

I really don't understand what I did wrong!

What should we do to use pre-commit and have a real modification of the files rather than just an indication of which files should be modified ?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Anthony Sottile answer I was able to correct the configuration to avoid conflicts between black and isort.
This is the config files that i use now:

```
$ more .pre-commit-config.yaml
repos:

-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks: # general hooks
    -   id: check-added-large-files
    -   id: check-ast
    -   id: check-case-conflict
    -   id: check-docstring-first
    -   id: check-json
    -   id: check-merge-conflict
    -   id: check-toml
    -   id: check-xml
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: debug-statements
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: fix-encoding-pragma
    -   id: name-tests-test
    -   id: trailing-whitespace

-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 23.1.0
    hooks: # code formatter
    -   id: black
        language: python
        args: ["--line-length=79"]

-   repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
    rev: 6.0.0
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
        name: flake8 under python3
        language_version: python3

-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.12.0
    hooks: # imports sorting
    -   id: isort
        name: isort (python)

-   repo: https://github.com/econchick/interrogate
    rev: 1.5.0
    hooks: # documentation checker
    -   id: interrogate
        args: [--fail-under=80, -vv]


$ more pyproject.toml
[tool.black]
line-length = 79
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
)/
'''

#[tool.flake8]
#max-line-length = 79
#exclude = [".git", "__pycache__", "dist"]
#extend-ignore = ["E203", "E266", "E501", "W503", "F403", "F401"]
#max-complexity = 10

[tool.isort]
atomic = true
profile = "black"
line_length = 79
skip_gitignore = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two tools which are conflicting on style -- likely `black` wants it one way and `isort` wants it another way

you'll need to configure `isort` with `profile = black` such that they don't conflict

Comment: Great! Many thanks to Anthony Sottile for his help. I now have another problem with flake8. There are always messages with flake8 indicating the problems found in the files but without modifying them. I have deleted flake8 for the moment until I find out what to do. I I have added an edit to the initial question with the new config files used. Maybe there is still an error in there that would explain why it doesn't work properly with flake8?

Comment: flake8 is not a formatter -- you need to fix things